# PHP Connection issues on one page, but not the previous (same connect code)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, connection

would appreciate if somebody could help me figure out this error. On my first page, let's call it "index.php", I have code at the start of my body to connect to my database and there is no problem. Connection is made and a variable from the database is displayed on the page. I have another page which uses pretty identical code for connecting, however I am receiving this error on my page:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /var/sites/s/ssangar.com/public_html/PMWebsite/projects.php on line 36
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /var/sites/s/ssangar.com/public_html/PMWebsite/projects.php on line 36
>
> Warning: mysql_numrows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/sites/s/ssangar.com/public_html/PMWebsite/projects.php on line 37

My php code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
</head>

<body>

  <?php 
  $connect = mysqli_connect("server", "username", "password", "database");
  $user = $_SESSION['username'];
  $query="SELECT * FROM Projects";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  $num=mysql_numrows($result);
  ?>



 ...

          <?php 
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo  "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder'>";
            echo  "<h4>". $row['title'] . "</h4><br/>";
            echo  "". $row['description'] ."<br/>";
            echo "Due: ". $row['deadline'] ."";
            echo "<span class='text-muted'></span>";
            echo " </div>";
          } 
          mysqli_close($connect);
          ?>

        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I also receive an error for the code near the bottom to display the contents of the database:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/sites/s/ssangar.com/public_html/PMWebsite/projects.php on line 83

Answer (score 0):

Worked out by getting rid of the $num=.... line, it worked perfectly!

new code:`$connect = mysqli_connect("server", "username", "pw", "");
      $user = $_SESSION['username'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Projects"; 
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);`